# How do I check for the presence of fields in logstash events?

Tags: logstash

Given the following logstash configuration:

```
input { stdin {}
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "foo (?<bar>.*)",
                  "message", "quux (?<stuff>.*)"
        ]
    }

    if "bar" in [tags] {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "had_bar" => "yup"}
        }
    }
}

output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```

I would expect a message starting with `"foo "` to get the field `had_bar` added to my event. However, when I try it:

```
* bin/logstash -f simple.conf
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1G
foo bar quux
{
       "message" => "foo bar quux",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-05-14T09:46:15.498Z",
          "host" => "my-dev-machine.com",
           "bar" => "bar quux"
}
```

What have I done wrong? I'm aware that grok also provides an `add_field` option, but I only want to add the field when I encounter the first pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking for fields in `tags`, but `tags` is just a normal field on the event. What you want is:

```
if [bar] {
    # ...
}
```